# fb like button shows allways as locale en_US

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like, locale

I am using the XFBML Facebook like button on my german website.
The locales were changed to de_DE to display "Gefällt mir" and it worked for some days.
But now it is ignoring the locales and everybody sees "Like".

I can not figure out why it has changed. 
The used code is the same as before.
The used web server is located in germany.
My facebook account is set to german language.

What else could have an effect?

Comment: So you have <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js"></script> on your code?

Comment: Yes, the code looks like: <div id="fb-root">
 <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1&amp;appId=XXXXXX"></script>
        <fb:like send="false" width="90" show_faces="false" font="arial" layout="button_count"></fb:like>   
    </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found my mistake...
My CMS also uses the possibility to login using a FB account.
For that it loads the javascript sdk again in the footer of the page.
This version was set to en_US!

Answer (score 0):

which version of the javascript sdk u are loading in your page that contains the like button?
make sure you are loading the de_DE version

Comment: The code looks like: <div id="fb-root"> <script src="connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1&amp;appId=xxxxx"></script> <fb:like send="false" width="90" show_faces="false" font="arial" layout="button_count"></fb:like> </div>